# Getting a particular Rails object type using meta-programming? Is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, metaprogramming

So I have a join table that relates to multiple models and stores the appropriate id and class like so:

```
Statistics
-----------------------------------
|object_type | object_id | value  |
-----------------------------------
| "User"     |     1     |  100   |
-----------------------------------
| "Post"     |     61    |  50    |
-----------------------------------
```

I was hoping to use metaprogramming to do pass the "object_type" and somehow and use the resulting object like so:

```
send("User").find(1)        #i.e. User.find(1)
send("Post").find(61)       #     Post.find(61)
```

Is there any good way to do this short of constructing a complicated if-else or case statement (i.e. if object_type == "User"...) ???

Comment: Not sure how this is metaprogramming. That aside, I'm not sure I get the point--wouldn't the existing association give you the correct type already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes are named with constants, so you can turn strings into classes easily with [const_get](http://ruby-doc.info/classes/Module.html#M001257):

```
self.class.const_get("User").find(1)
```

or

```
Object.const_get("User").find(1)
```

But it's generally better to use the first version as it's closer to what you get when you refer to the class directly.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're in Rails, ActiveSupport gives you String#constantize by way of http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize. That would probably be the most "railsy" way of handling it. It does simply use const_get behind the scenes, but it also has some logic to help avoid errors.

Comment: BTW, recently `safe_constantize` was added to return `nil` instead of throwing exception.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's actually a good solution but eval just works. Maybe there is some reason not to do this way, don't know

```
eval("User").find(1)
```